# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid URL for class: jar:rsrc:javafx.graphics.jar!/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.class

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to run an application using the command prompt. It's built in Eclipse, using JavaFx. It's a digital diary program that I've been writing for a while and would like to send it to some friends. It is exported with packaged libraries as a runnable jar file.

I'm using the line

```
java -jar -Djavafx.verbose=true main.jar --module-path /users/home/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

to run it.

I've traced the errors (through use of `-Djavafx.verbose=true`) to java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.

One of them is as follows:

```
WARNING: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid URL for class: jar:rsrc:javafx.graphics.jar!/com/sun/glass/utils/NativeLibLoader.class
```

What's causing this error?

---

EDIT after moving the --add-modules before main.jar, I get some new errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  ...
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = main
  ...
```

Comment: “It is exported with packaged libraries as a runnable jar file” - > please, edit the question. Explain what you did to produce your jar file, so that somebody could replicate the steps.  List what is in the jar, so that somebody could compare their jar content with yours.

Comment: What is the exact command-line option you are using to run your application? (full text).

Comment: The java man page states "When you use -jar, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.".  I assume the module-path will still be used as it is not the class path, but I don't know.

Comment: The [java man page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) states "Arguments following ... -jar jarfile ... are passed as arguments to the main class."  So, if you use the argument order from your question, then the module path is being passed as arguments to your application, not the VM.

Comment: so how do I pass the arguments to the VM instead? also, the full command line is `java -jar -Djavafx.verbose=true main.jar --module-path /users/home/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`

Comment: @jewelsea: not always. It's common to keep `-jar jarfile` together, but if you separate them `java abc -jar def jarfile ghi` it is the options after `-jar` AND `jarfile` namely `ghi` that are passed to the app; both `abc` and `def` are processed by JVM. protocol: put (at least) `main.jar` after the `--add-modules blah`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 alright, I did that and got something else instead.

Comment: It would appear that the fix to change the location of the module arguments in your command line which was suggested by dave actually answered your original question and resolved it.

Comment: The new IllegalStateException issue would appear unrelated to me.  Usually, such an exception occurs because you have tried to perform operations affecting objects (e.g. nodes) shared with the JavaFX framework off of the JavaFX application thread.  There is not enough information in your question to provide a suggested fix.  If you want further assistance with it, I advise asking a new question and, in it, providing the complete stack trace (formatted as code) and a [mcve], so that somebody could copy and paste to run without change and replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying arguments for the java virtual machine being run with a `-jar` command, these arguments need to go before the jar file name in the command line.

*Do not use this*

It will treat the module arguments as program arguments rather than VM arguments:

```
java -jar -Djavafx.verbose=true main.jar --module-path /users/home/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

*Instead, use this*

```
java --module-path /users/home/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -Djavafx.verbose=true -jar main.jar
```